# How can I create an android dialog from my HTML page?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

Every activity within my android app is generated using HTML. When one of the images is touched, I would like to bring up an android dialog like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList). How can I achieve this? I'm assuming javascript, but I have no idea how.

Comment: So that android dialog example isn't what you are looking for code-wise?

Comment: Did you read this? http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-webview-detect-html-element-on.html

Comment: @summea that shows me how to create a dialog, but not how to communicate HTML to activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `WebView` with `addJavascriptInterface()`. This adds a bridge from javascript to native Android code, allowing you to trigger a dialog from HTML.

See example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a WebView for showing the HTML files.
If you do so, you could use a custom [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and implement the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method to handle a click on your images in the activity.

You add the WebViewClient to your WebView via the [`setWebClient()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) method.